# Compute difference between field and aggregated field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to run complex aggregation and one of its steps is computing sum of sold_qty field, and then I need to subtract this sum with non aggregated field all_qty. My data looks like:

```
{item_id: XXX, sold_qty: 1, all_qty: 20, price: 100 }
{item_id: XXX, sold_qty: 3, all_qty: 20, price: 100 }
{item_id: YYY, sold_qty: 1, all_qty: 20, price: 80 }
```

These are transactions from offer. The all_qty and price fields are redundant - express single values from other structure - offers and just duplicated in all transactions from single offer (identified by item_id).

In the terms of SQL what I need is:

```
SELECT (all_qty - sum(sold_qty)) * price GROUP BY item_id
```

What I've done is aggregation

```
'{
"query": {"term": {"seller": 9059247}},
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "group_by_offer": {
    "terms": { "field": "item_id", size: 0},
    "aggs": { "sold_sum": {"sum": {"field": "sold_qty"}}}
}
}
}'
```

But I don't know what to do next to achieve my goal.

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already storing redundant fields, if I were you, I would also store the result of `all_price = all_qty * price` and `sold_price = sold_qty * price`. It's is not mandatory but it will be faster at execution time than executing scripts to make the same computation.

```
{item_id: XXX, sold_qty: 1, sold_price: 20,  all_qty: 20, price: 100, all_price: 2000 }
{item_id: XXX, sold_qty: 3, sold_price: 300, all_qty: 20, price: 100, all_price: 2000 }
{item_id: YYY, sold_qty: 1, sold_price: 80,  all_qty: 20, price: 80,  all_price: 1600 }
```

All you'd have to do next is to sum `sold_price` and average `all_price` and simply get the difference between both using a `bucket_script` pipeline aggregation:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "seller": 9059247
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_offer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "item_id",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sold_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sold_price"
          }
        },
        "all_sum": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "all_price"
          }
        },
        "diff": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "sold": "sold_sum",
              "all": "all_sum"
            },
            "script": "params.all - params.sold"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```